# Is it possible to have a pseudo element within pseudo element?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

```css
div { position: relative; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: #f00; }
div::before { position: absolute; content: ''; width: 75px; height: 75px; background: #0f0; }
div::before::before { position: absolute; content: ''; width: 50px; height: 50px; background: #00f; }
```

Is my syntax wrong or is pseudo-element within pseudo-element not supported?

Note that I am aware about the `::after` pseudo-element, though I need an actual element within another pseudo-element to achieve, e.g. where `::after` does not suffice is:

```css
div { position: relative; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: #f00; }
div::before { position: absolute; content: ''; right: 0; bottom: 0; width: 75px; height: 75px; background: #0f0; }
div::after { position: absolute; content: ''; left: 0; top: 0; width: 50px; height: 50px; background: #00f; }
```

Because `::after` is relative to the element and not `::before`.

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/q/9007546/703717

Comment: Because you are doing `absolute` positioning, there is no reason to not use `:after`, it just needs to have its position calculated in some respect to the position of `:before` (see http://jsfiddle.net/dBj3c/4/ which puts the `:after` where it would be if it was in fact possible to be a `:before:before` based on your code above).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is my syntax wrong or is pseudo-element within pseudo-element not supported?

If I understand you correctly, it isn't possible. You can't chain multiple pseudo-elements as of [Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements) though it  apparently may be allowed in the future.

> Only one pseudo-element may appear per selector, and if present it must appear after the sequence of simple selectors that represents the subjects of the selector. **Note:** A future version of this specification may allow multiple pseudo-elements per selector.

---

Interestingly, you *can* chain the `::first-letter` & `::before` / `::after` pseudo-elements with the placeholder pseudo element, e.g.

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder::first-letter {
color: purple;  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k3yb6/1/

Comment: “it will apparently be allowed once Selectors Level 4 is adopted by browsers” — Selectors level 4 doesn’t (currently) allow multiple pseudo-elements either: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#pseudo-elements.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite: True, but considering it's a WD things may change by the time it's CR or further. Thanks for pointing that out though.

Comment: indeedio. I think lines like that are sometimes put in W3C specs quite speculatively (i.e. not due to actual plans for implementing what they describe), but I don’t have any actual knowledge either way.

Comment: @Paul, Adrift: It was explored as early as Generated Content level 3: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#nesting Needless to say, however, it never took off. Also notice how old the module is - if it's not pending a rewrite, it's probably abandoned.