# Can I nest the pseudo-element after?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I found it from W3C. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#nesting

> 4.2.1. Nesting '::before' and '::after' pseudo-elements
>
> The selector '::before::before' represents a pseudo-element contained at the start of a pseudo-element contained at the start of an element.
> For example, the following rules:
> div { content: 'A' }
> div::before { content: 'B'; }
> div::before::before { content: 'C'; }
> ...would result in the following rendering objects:

```
,-----------------------.
| ,---------.           |
| | ,---.   |           |
| | | C | B | A         |
| | `---'   |           |
| `---------'           |
`-----------------------'
```

But it was not work in Chrome 30. http://codepen.io/tychio/pen/pLDqm

So I just want to ask how can use `after` or `before` to nest.

Comment: You can nest pseudo-classes, but `::after` is a pseudo-element, and you can't nest pseudo-elements.

Comment: @BoltClock Oh, my miswriting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

True, that module was proposed, but unfortunately not implemented by any browser.

So for now you can't do this.

Edit: Just found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9007628/703717)

Comment: Thanks. Have you more infomation? Which browser vendors will support it in future?

Comment: @Tychio, sorry I don't know any additional info about future support